# How can I change the ESCDELAY value for C ncurses when I'm statically linking the libraries at compile time?

Tags: c, compilation, static-libraries, static-linking, ncurses

I have a program that I wrote using the C ncurses library. In this program, near the top I have this line:

```
ESCDELAY = 0;
```

This line is used to remove the delay that comes when pressing the escape key in ncurses.

I can compile this program normally like so:

```
gcc program.c -o program -lncurses
```

I have the correct libraries for static linking installed and set up, but when I try to compile my program statically:

```
gcc -static program.c -o program -lncurses
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libncurses.a(lib_getch.o):(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `ESCDELAY'; /tmp/ccMFQAm6.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

When I remove the `ESCDELAY = 0;` line from my code and compile it statically like before, it compiles and works just fine.

So, how can I statically compile my code while changing the ESCDELAY value?

Comment: is it possible to use `set_escdelay(0);` instead of assigning the global variable?

Comment: Is the line `ESCDELAY = 0;` *outside* of a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For man [`set_escdelay`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_threads.3x.html):

> The **`ESCDELAY`** and **`TABSIZE`** global variables are modified by some applications. To modify them in any configuration, use the **`set_escdelay`** or **`set_tabsize`** functions. Other global variables are not modifiable.

You should replace

```
ESCDELAY = 0;
```

by

```
set_escdelay(0);
```